# Integrating a later version of Solr in Crafter CMS 2.5+

Tags: solr

What is the level of effort to integrate a later version of Solr (6+) with Crafter CMS (2.5+)?

Answer (score 0):

My approach would be to get the default solrconfig.xml for the old and new Solr versions. Compare them, in particular the parts that the CMS seems to be using.

Solrconfig.xml can be over 2000 lines, so comparison can seem overwhelming, but it is not so bad if you focus on the relevant parts. You may find that nothing much changed which affects you. Sorry for being vague here.

If you find yourself in schema problems, then your easy way out is to remove schema.xml and enable managed schema mode. That can simplify configuration immensely.

Have a look at the great new Suggester and Highlighter features. But using them will of course increase your 'level of effort'. HTH -- Rick